# Why can't the IIS installer can't copy staxmem.dll despite it being in the folder specified?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I'm running Microsoft Web Platform Installer and it's trying to install IIS5.1. Unfortunately I've got the following error:

> Setup cannot copy the file staxmem.dll
>
> Ensure that the location specified below is correct, or change it and insert 'Windows XP Proffessional Service Pack 3 CD' in the drive you specify.
>
> c:\windows\ServicePackFiles\i386

Now I downloaded the service pack through Windows Update so I don't have the CD. I did a search via Google and came up with [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894351). I followed the first set of instructions and there wasn't anything wrong with the database, so I proceeded to step 2. Unfortunately this again requires the Service Pack CD.

A search of the hard-drive has shown that the file is in the directory specified.

So how do I get the installation to proceed?

Is it because the file already exists at the target location and is in use? If so that would imply that IIS is already installed on the machine. So in that case the question becomes - why is the Web Platform Installer trying to install something that's already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this question over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/240/why-cant-the-iis-installer-cant-copy-staxmem-dll-despite-it-being-in-the-folder) (partly to kick start my account over there) and got the answer. This is the relevant part of the answer:

> That support page is misleading. When
>   it says if the tool returns the
>   message:
>
> "This operation may find that this
>   database is corrupt"
>
> It means does the output contains that
>   text somewhere? Not is that the only
>   output. The output will still look
>   mostly like the second sample, but
>   with the line above somewhere in the
>   output. Even if the tool finds
>   possible corruption, it will still end
>   the output saying "Integrity Check
>   Successful".

So all sorted now. I should have tried that straight away, but the support page appeared to be clear cut about which solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened on Win2k3 server I would guess it was because the ServicePackFiles folder had been deleted from C:\Windows. I don't know if XP uses the same mechanism, but it would be worth checking. If the original installation did not have SP3, and SP3 was subsequently installed, then the ServicePackFiles folder holds the SP3 versions of install files (possibly including staxmem.dll). If the ServicePackFiles folder can't be found the installer prompts for the files it needs, but it will only accept the SP3 version.

You could try reinstalling SP3 then trying the Web Platform install again.

JR

Comment: The service pack files folder exists and is at the location specified in the dialog. The files exist in both C:\windows\system32 and C:\windows\servicepackfiles\i386 and the sizes, dates and version numbers are identical (for the files I've checked).

Comment: So much for that idea :-( I wonder if the Web Platform Installer wants an old version of staxmem.dll.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to corruption of secedit.sdb.
i.e. secedit.sdb in %windir%\security\database- may be damaged.

RESOLUTION

1. Make a backup copy of secedit.sdb file.
2. Open a command prompt (click Start, Run, and then type "cmd". press Enter.)
3. Run `esentutl /p %windir%\security\database\secedit.sdb`
   and press Enter. Click "OK" when presented with "Repair" warning. Wait for repair to finish.
4. Return to the 'add windows components' dialog, make sure that the specified folder is your Windows installation folder and click OK. Installation of IIS component(s) should complete normally.